# Mapping not working when creating a model with Ext.create?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

When I create a model using Ext.create() in ExtJs 4.2+, I am expecting the mapping to fill the model but it does not seem to do it. Is it a normal behavior?

If I use a model with mapping in a store, the mapping works fine...

Example not working:

http://jsfiddle.net/B6v6v/

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.file', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'name',
            mapping:'label'
        }]
});

var rec = Ext.create("MyApp.model.file",{"label":"TEST"});
console.log(rec.get("name"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's normal. The mapping is for transforming data coming in from the server into something readable in your model. If you already have the data, why not just use the correct key?

If you must, you can do something like:

`MyApp.model.File.getProxy().getReader().readRecords([{}, {}, {}]);`

Comment: I get data from many Ext.Ajax.request() calls from a rest api. The model is already in use in another store and I wanted to rely on the same model here...

Comment: Working fine! Thanks... I'll also try with a temporary store with addRecords param set to true...

Comment: while creating can we do something so the mapping remains the same? as i will be using it to add to a final array of records and based on which my grid will so the ui.